# SQL Apache Derby - Select last value in column

Tags: sql, select, derby

I am using Apache Derby and am trying to select the last value in a column.

Currently I have the following:

```
SELECT id FROM hotels ORDER BY id DESC WHERE ROWNUM <=1;
```

However this is resulting in a syntax error:

```
Syntax error: Encountered "WHERE" at line 1, column 44.
```

Would anyone know the proper way to write this query?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `order by` clause goes after the `where`.  Perhaps you intend:

```
SELECT MAX(id)
FROM hotels;
```

Comment: Thanks for that Gordon.